# SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode. Can't insert data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, locked

I am a novice to Android programming and am creating an barter-system app.

I've used SQLite as the Database and have created a DatabaseHelper class.

The app starts with a Login page and has a link to the Register user page. It is when inserting values into the users database that I keep getting the SQLite Database is locked code 5 exception. I've searched everywhere for an answer and have tried using transaction controls and, I think I've closed the database whenever required.

I am truly lost and have no idea how to proceed with my app.  I've added my log and DatabaseHandler class. Please do look through and help me debug this program.

```
04-15 14:35:39.046 2631-2631/? E/SQLiteLog: (5) database is locked
04-15 14:35:39.046 2631-2631/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.asas.handmedown/databases/userDB.db'.
                                             android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:320)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:294)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:1142)
                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:267)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                 at com.example.asas.handmedown.MyDBHandler.addUser(MyDBHandler.java:96)
                                                 at com.example.asas.handmedown.SignupActivity.addButtonClicked(SignupActivity.java:117)
                                                 at com.example.asas.handmedown.SignupActivity$1.onClick(SignupActivity.java:44)
                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here is my DatabaseHandler class.

```
    public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDB.db";

    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERID = "_userid";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERPWD = "userpwd";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERBATCH = "userbatch";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERMOB = "usermob";


    public static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEMID = "_itemid";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEMUID = "_userid";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEMNAME = "itemname";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEMDESC = "itemdesc";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEMPRICE = "itemprice";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEMIMG = "itemimg";

    private static MyDBHandler sInstance;
    /*public static synchronized MyDBHandler getInstance(Context context){
        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
        if (sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new MyDBHandler(context.getApplicationContext(), DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }*/

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String query_users = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" +
                COLUMN_USERID +  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USERPWD + " TEXT," + COLUMN_USERBATCH + " TEXT,"+
                COLUMN_USERMOB + " NUMBER" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query_users);



        String query_items = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ITEMID +  " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + COLUMN_ITEMUID + " NUMBER, " +
                COLUMN_ITEMNAME + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ITEMDESC + " TEXT," + COLUMN_ITEMPRICE+ " NUMBER,"+
                COLUMN_ITEMIMG + "BLOB" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query_items);
        db.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS);
        onCreate(db);
        db.close();

    }

    //Add row to the database
    public void addUser(User user) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USERID, user.get_id());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, user.get_username());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERPWD, user.get_userpwd());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERBATCH, user.get_userbatch());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERMOB, user.get_usermob());

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);

        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();


    }
    public void addItem(Item item) {

        try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(item.get_itemimg());
            byte[] image = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(image);

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMID, item.get_id());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMUID, item.get_userid());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMNAME, item.get_itemname());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMDESC, item.get_itemdesc());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMPRICE, item.get_itemprice());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMIMG, image);

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
            db.close();

            fis.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Error
        }

    }

    //delete product from database
    public void deleteUser(int userId){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERID + " =\"" + userId + "\";");
        db.close();
    }


    //delete product from database
    public void deleteItem(int itemId){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ITEMID + " =\"" + itemId + "\";");
        db.close();
    }

    //update user details
    public void updateUser(User user){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USERID, user.get_id());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, user.get_username());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERPWD, user.get_userpwd());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERBATCH, user.get_userbatch());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERMOB, user.get_usermob());

        db.update(TABLE_USERS, values, COLUMN_USERID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(user.get_id())});
        db.close();
        db.endTransaction();

    }

    public void updateItem(Item item){

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(item.get_itemimg());
            byte[] image = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(image);

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMID, item.get_id());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMUID, item.get_userid());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMNAME, item.get_itemname());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMDESC, item.get_itemdesc());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMPRICE, item.get_itemprice());
            values.put(COLUMN_ITEMIMG,image);

            db.update(TABLE_ITEMS, values, COLUMN_ITEMID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(item.get_id())});
            db.close();

            fis.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Error
        }

    }


    //print out the users table as a string
    public User userDatabaseToString(int userId){

        String dbString = "";
        User user = new User();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERID + " = " + userId;

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        //Move to the 1st row in ur results
        c.moveToFirst();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERID))!=null){

                user.set_id(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERID)));
                user.set_username(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME)));
                user.set_userpwd(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERPWD)));
                user.set_userbatch(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERBATCH)));
                user.set_usermob(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERMOB)));

                //dbString += "\n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        db.endTransaction();
        return user;
    }

    //print out the items table as a string
    public Item itemDatabaseToString(int itemId){

        String dbString = "";
        Item item = new Item();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ITEMID + " = " + itemId;

        //Cursor points to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        //Move to the 1st row in ur results
        c.moveToFirst();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMID))!=null){

                item.set_id(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMID)));
                item.set_userid(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMUID)));
                item.set_itemname(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMNAME)));
                item.set_itemdesc(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMDESC)));
                item.set_itemprice(c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMPRICE)));
                item.set_itemimg("ImagePath");

                //dbString += "\n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return item;
    }

    //to get Item Image
    public Bitmap getItemImage(int itemId){

        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ITEMID + " = " + itemId;
        Bitmap bmp=null;

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMID))!=null){

                byte[] image=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMIMG));
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return bmp;
    }

    //search for occurance in user database
    public boolean searchUserOccurance(int userId){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERID + " = " + userId;

        Log.d("search",query);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.getCount() <= 0){
            c.close();
            return false;
        }

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERID)) == userId){
                return true;
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        db.endTransaction();
        return false;
    }

    //search for occurance in items database
    public boolean searchItemOccurance(int itemId){

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ITEMID + " = " + itemId;

        Log.d("search",query);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c.getCount() <= 0){
            c.close();
            return false;
        }

        while(!c.isAfterLast()){
            if (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ITEMID)) == itemId){
                return true;
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've not used any explicit threads in my program code, since because I am not well versed in thread programming.

Comment: what is line  96 in adduser method

Comment: @Selvin Yes. Thank you for that. 
I've changed it and tried running the program again. Sadly no changes.
Do I use    setTransactionSuccessful()    to commit?

Comment: @ankitagrawal is it this?
    values.put(COLUMN_USERMOB, user.get_usermob());
I'm trying to insert a value for the user's mobile number,

Comment: @Selvin I've tried using setTransactionSuccessful too. Please suggest what else to try.

Comment: please remove db.close and use setTransactionSuccessful as selvin suggested

Comment: @ankitagrawal Do I remove all db.close, and only use db.setTransactionSuccessful?

Comment: please refer to the question listed as having answer for same problem, it will help you